# How to access the stored array in class

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I want to access the array i have filled throughout the for loop,however what i get it is still empty array when call fill_particles().particles, is there any way to get rid of this problem? here is my code.

```
class particle(object):
  def __init__(self,x,y,z):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.z=z
class fill_particles():
   def __init__(self):

    self.particles=[]
     
   def fill(self):
    for i in range(5):
      self.particles.append(particle(i,i+1,i+2))
```

Comment: That's because you didn't call `fill`?

Comment: First create an object, then call fill and then check for particles in the object.

Comment: your code is missing the actual usage of the class (which I think will show that your are not calling `fill()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class and call `fill()`.  Here's a working example, along with extra functions for display purposes:

```py
class Particle(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Particle(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, z={self.z})'

class Particles:

    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = []

    def fill(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.particles.append(Particle(i, i + 1, i + 2))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Particles({self.particles!r})'

particles = Particles()
print(particles)
particles.fill()
print(particles)
```

Output:

```
Particles([])
Particles([Particle(x=0, y=1, z=2), Particle(x=1, y=2, z=3), Particle(x=2, y=3, z=4), Particle(x=3, y=4, z=5), Particle(x=4, y=5, z=6)])
```